# What is the meaning of the formula $f_D = \frac{2v}\lambda$ in the context of the Doppler effect?

Tags: waves, doppler-effect

I'm reading the French Wikipedia article on [laser vibrometers](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vibrom%C3%A8tre_laser). With no real context, the article states that if a wave reflects off of a vibrating object, the value of the "frequency shift" is:

$$f_D = \frac {2v} \lambda$$

where $v$ is the velocity of the vibrating object and $\lambda$ is the wavelength. What is the meaning of this formula? When I try to work out the frequency shift myself, I come up with $\frac v \lambda$, I can't see where the $2$ comes from.

Comment: Assume that the speed of the vibrating object is much less than the speed of light. When an image of an object, which is moving towards a mirror at a speed $v$, is viewed in the mirror the image is seen to be moving at a speed of $2v$ towards the object. So $2v$ is the relative speed between the source (the moving image) and the observer (stationary relative to the source).

Comment: @Farcher I don't understand. I can see that the relative velocity between a moving point and its image is $2v$, but what does that have to do with the frequency of a reflected beam? When one peak of the wave hits a moving mirror, the next one has to travel a distance $\lambda$ at a relative speed of $c-v$, $v$ being the speed of the mirror. So the new frequency is $(c-v)/\lambda$ and the frequency shift is $v/\lambda$.

Comment: You have to be careful using $c-v$ etc because you are dealing with light with the speed of light being constant. The Doppler equation which you should use is $\frac{\Delta f}{f} \approx \frac v c$ where $v$ is the relative speed between the source and the observer.

Comment: @Farcher Do we really need relativity in order to understand this result? Are you saying that in a classical mechanical model of light, the formula in my question is wrong?

Comment: The standard derivations for the Doppler effect for mechanical waves cannot be used for electromagnetic waves. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_Doppler_effect